# how to add a sub select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following working mysql query that looks for duplicates:

```
SELECT TSTVersion_ID, 
       xTSTVersions.TSTVersion,
       TSTPatch
FROM xTSTVersions
INNER JOIN (SELECT TSTVersion    
          FROM xTSTVersions
          GROUP BY TSTVersion 
      HAVING count(TSTVersion) > 1) dup
ON xTSTVersions.TSTVersion = dup.TSTVersion
```

Now, I need to make the following changes as I want to get a list that are NOT duplicates
and then join an additional column from another table - Licenses, column is Program
or (Licenses.Program) which can be joined with table xTSTVersions using a common column Version_ID from both tables.

I figure, I have to change the dup query to grab the records I want:

```
HAVING count(TSTVersion) = 1 ) nondups
```

Now, that I have my list of nondups, how do I edit the query to ADD my new column from this other table(Licenses.Program)?

Does this become like a sub select?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT TSTVersion_ID, 
       xTSTVersions.TSTVersion,
       TSTPatch,
       Licenses.Program
FROM xTSTVersions
INNER JOIN (SELECT TSTVersion    
          FROM xTSTVersions
          GROUP BY TSTVersion 
      HAVING count(TSTVersion) = 1) dup
ON xTSTVersions.TSTVersion = dup.TSTVersion
INNER JOIN Licenses
ON xTSTVersions.TSTVersion_ID = Licenses.TSTVersion_ID
```

Comment: before the adding the INNER JOIN, my current list had like 40 records. As soon as I added the INNER JOIN to Licenses, then I got a count of 2 records only. What I was expecting was for every TSTVersion_ID, that I would grab the Program.

Comment: @oramel Maybe you need LEFT JOIN, but in this case Program will be NULL for some TSTVersion_ID (which don't exist in Licenses)

Comment: thanks,we got most of it. Can I still filter out the NULLs for Program? I tried `AND Program IS NOT NULL` but that won't work.

Comment: @oramel If you don't want to show the rows where PROGRAM IS NULL then use INNER JOIN.

Comment: @oramel Maybe the problem is that you filtered the rows which don't have dublicates, but you need to remove dublicates. For example, there are 3 rows with TSTVersion = 5. So it has dublicates and you removed it at all. But you need to leave only one row with TSTVersion = 5

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a standard join:

```
INNER JOIN xTSTVersions on xTSTVersions.Version_ID = TSVersion.Version_ID
```

Comment: Yeah, mistyping the name of the second table (TSVersion instead of Licenses) was clearly a good reason to vote that down. The word "version" only appeared like 11 times in SO's query so I'm sure I must be an idiot for not wrapping my head around it all in like 14 seconds. Am I supposed to write a primer on SQL and what an inner join does to get some credit? You might notice that the accepted has exactly what I said...an inner join. I'm so sick of stackoverflow.